# Python using doctest on the mainline

Tags: python, string, doctest

Hello i was wondering if it is possible and if so how? to do doctests or something similar from the mainline, instead of testing a function as is described in the doctest docs
i.e.

```
"""
>>> 
Hello World
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello"
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

This is part of being able to test students scripts against a docstring, i found this snipet of code that allows me to input both as strongs

```
import doctest
from doctest import DocTestRunner, DocTestParser
enter code here
def run_doctest(code, test):
    import doctest
    from doctest import DocTestRunner, DocTestParser
    code = code + '\n__dtest=__parser.get_doctest(__test, globals(), "Crunchy Doctest", "crunchy", 0)\n__runner.run(__dtest)\n'
    runner = DocTestRunner()
    parser = DocTestParser()
    exec code in {'__runner':runner, '__parser':parser, '__test':test}
```

that does more or less but it seems hardly ideal, an suggestions on either point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doctest` is *not* limited to testing functions.  For example, if `dt.py` is:

```
'''
  >>> foo
  23
'''

foo = 23

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

then, e.g.:

```
$ py26 dt.py -v
Trying:
    foo
Expecting:
    23
ok
1 items passed all tests:
   1 tests in __main__
1 tests in 1 items.
1 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

(works just as well without the `-v`, but then it wouldn't have much to show: just silence;-).  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nah i am more after getting what happens if the program runs normally

Comment: ...and?  What's not "normal" about running the main script's body, then the doctest?  Doesn't seem any different from what your convoluted code is doing -- e.g., the `foo = 23` (followed by the check that `foo` is `23`) in my A's example.  Please edit your Q to supply examples of what kind of things you expect in lieu of the `enter code here` and why simply running the module's doctests (after its body) is not what you want, because I think I'm confused;-).

Comment: for example testing the output of the program (i.e. the regular stuff that comes out via print)

Comment: @Hugoagogo, for the purpose of testing the whole of any program's stdout against a known (aka "golden") expected result, `doctest` is not optimal (you're using it well outside its design parameters). Rather, use `subprocess` to run the other program, capturing its output, and `assertListEqual` (see http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual) to check that list of lines vs a list of lines prepared from a "reference" (aka "golden") file; or, use `difflib`, http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html, for subtler comparisons (e.g. ignoring whitespace &c).

Comment: mmm that was my original path, but i wanted to be able to use that as well as standard doctests, i might have to try and use both in combination

Comment: @Hugo, sure, if you want to test _both_ the program's whole stdout _and_ the value of some expressions at program's end, doctest on module docstring (as per my A) _plus_ "golden-file test" (as per my previous comment) can both be used.